# extract nested archives to get content

Tags: powershell, zip, extract, unzip, 7zip

I have nested archives that am trying to extract, it has following format so archive1.zip is main other archives are nested inside each other I need to get folder directory extracted.

- archive1.zip/

  - archive2.tar/

    - archive3.7z/

      - folder/

        - file.txt

I tried the following :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName } | Split-Path | Get-Unique |

ForEach-Object { cd $_; 7z x * -r -aou  -o"$path" }
```

But I can only get **archive2.tar** as output

Comment: `& "7z.exe" e -an -air!*.rar -r -o"Parent of archive1.zip"`

Comment: It seems not to work doesn't extract any archive , archives format not .rar even when trying with wildcard * it only extracts one level  giving as output archive2.tar

Comment: I posted the comment because it worked for me a few months ago.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it by using a loop as follows extracting archive then deleting it and so on.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path
$extension = ".tar|.zip|.7z"

1..3 | % {

$zip = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File  | where {$_.Extension -match $extension} | ForEach-Object { $_.Name }
$files | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName } | Split-Path | Get-Unique |
ForEach-Object { Set-Location $_; 7z x * -aou -o"$path"; Remove-Item $zip}

}
```